# can self.left be recognized as a variable in pformat({f"{self.value}": (self.left, self.right)}, indent=1)?

Tags: python, pprint

I use the codes below to print the structure of a tree. It do works, but I wonder in the last line how it recognize `self.left` and `self.right` as a variable rather than just a string? In my knowledge, variable should be enclosed by `{}` in f-string, but this differs.

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, value: int, parent: Node | None) -> None:
        self.value = value
        self.parent = parent
        self.right: Node | Node = None
        self.left: Node | Node = None

    def __repr__(self) -> str:
        if self.left is None and self.right is None:
            return str(self.value)
        return pformat({f"{self.value}": (self.left, self.right)}, indent=1)
```

Comment: self.left and self.right are not within your f-string

Comment: The f-string ends before the `:`. `self.left` and `self.right` are in a tuple in the value of the dictionary key.

Comment: And if `self.value` is a string, there's no need to put it in an f-string.